# How to implement a many-to-many hierarchical structure in MySQL

Tags: mysql, hierarchical-data

This is a follow-up from my question here: [How to record sequential collections of records in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9610942/how-to-record-sequential-collections-of-records-in-mysql)

In short, I want to implement in MySQL a table of recipes and another of instructions.  A recipe is a sequential series of instructions **or other recipes**.  So for example you could imagine a `Peach_preserve` recipe, and a `Peach_tart` that uses the `Peach_preserve`, plus a series of other steps (instructions).  `Peach_preserve` could be used for many other recipes.

In my previous question I was recommended a design to allow for a specific order for each instruction within a recipe:

```
recipe
id  name
1   Recipe1
2   Recipe2

recipe_instruction
recipe_id  instruction_id  sortorder
1          5               1
1          3               2
1          4               3
2          6               1
2          7               2
2          3               3
2          6               4
```

What I would like to do now is to incorporate the idea that within a recipe a sub-component might be another recipe rather than an atomic / discrete instruction.  So my idea is to do it this way:

```
recipe
id  name
1   Recipe1
2   Recipe2

recipe_instruction
recipe_id  step_id  isRecipe    sortorder
1          5             F           1
1          3             F           2
1          4             F           3
2          1             F           1
2          1             T           2
2          2             F           3
2          1             F           4
```

Here you can see that `Recipe1` is made of 3 instructions, and `Recipe2` is made of one instruction, then `Recipe1`, then another 2 instructions, one of which is a repeat of step 1.  I thought of other ways to capture this idea but they involve a bunch of null entries.  What I don't like in the above is that the key is made of the 4 attributes...

My questions are:

1. Is it a good idea to incorporate a recursive idea inside a db?
2. If so, is this the way to do it, or can it be improved upon?

QUICK EDIT:  I'm starting to read on hierarchies.  In my example, each one recipe can have several parents.

Comment: This is also known as a hierarchical query, or a bill-of-materials query.  It is related to representing trees in a DB.  If you've not researched on those terms, maybe you should.  There are a number of systems for handling such data structures.

Comment: Not sure it's a tree as each child can have many parent (i.e., a given recipe can be a sub-component of more than one recipe).

Comment: It's at least a DAG (directed acyclic graph).  Whether it is a tree depends on your definition of tree.  Mine clearly allows a node to have more than one other node pointing to it; mathematical terminology might preclude that (go discuss on math.stackexchange.com).  There's a bug in the data if it is not an acyclic data structure (but I bet few insertions would check for acyclicity - or whatever the approved term is).  But, it is a BOM (bill-of-materials) type structure, where (more or less by definition) things like 6mm nuts can be used in many different assemblies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very common technique. It is used to store hierarchical data (you call it recursive) within a db.

However you will have to manage the integrity in your application, because a foreign key cannot be used, since the relation is conditional to the isRecipe flag.

Comment: even if `isRecipe = T` the step_id can take any value, even 3, which is not a valid Recipe id. This is what I meant with integrity, you cannot enforce this with relational means, but you will have todo this within your application