# How to add a sort order to a MySQL closure table representing a many-to-many relationship?

Tags: mysql, hierarchical-data

This is a follow-up to my questions here:
[How to implement a many-to-many hierarchical structure in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9691366/how-to-implement-a-many-to-many-hierarchical-structure-in-mysql)
and here:
[How to record sequential collections of records in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9610942/how-to-record-sequential-collections-of-records-in-mysql).

In short, I want to implement in MySQL a table of recipes and another of instructions.  A recipe is a sequential series of instructions **or other recipes**.  So for example you could imagine a `Peach_preserve` recipe, and a `Peach_tart` that uses the `Peach_preserve`, plus a series of other steps (instructions).  `Peach_preserve` could be used for many other recipes.

I read [this blog post by Bill Karwin about closure tables](http://karwin.blogspot.com/2010/03/rendering-trees-with-closure-tables.html), and I think this solution best addresses my challenges (my hierarchy is many-to-many and the steps are sequential).  So for example I would have:

```
recipe
id  name
1   Peach preserve
2   Cubed peeled peaches
3   Fresh peaches
4   Powdered sugar
5   Cook together
6   Peel and cut in chunks
7   Mix

step (or instruction)
id  desc
1   Cook together
2   Buy peaches
3   Buy sugar
4   Peel and cut in chunks
5   Mix

recipe_instruction
(Ancestor) (Descendant)
recipe_id  step_id   depth  descendant_is_instruction
3          3         0      0
3          2         1      1
4          4         0      0
4          3         1      1
6          6         0      0
6          4         1      1
2          2         0      0
2          3         1      0
2          2         2      1
2          6         1      0
2          4         2      1
(and so on...)
```

I'm not a fan of the `descendant_is_instruction` flag, but I don't know how else to do that.  I suppose I could replace it with a `descendant_is_leaf` to identify terminal items...

The sort order is represented by a table that incorporates all the relationships at a depth of 1:

```
Depth=1 table
recipe_id  step_id      order
3           2            1
4           3            1
6           4            1
2           3            1
2           6            2
```

I'm simplifying here because in practice I would separate ingredients and instructions, but you get the idea.

So, is that a good way to combine both a hierarchical data structure and a notion of step order?  Anything I should do to improve / simplify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have done some research on my problem, leveraging mostly information provided here and elsewhere by Bill Karwin (I eventually decided to buy his book).  Based on this, I think the best option is to add a breadcrumbs column to my closure table, similarly to what Bill recommends here [MySQL Closure Table hierarchical database - How to pull information out in the correct order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8252323/mysql-closure-table-hierarchical-database-how-to-pull-information-out-in-the-c/8288201#8288201) .

The breadcrumbs would allow me to `ORDER BY`, which would solve my ordering problem.

I would find the terminal nodes by querying the closure table, looking for all nodes that have no ancestor other than themselves.

Answer (score 8):

> A recipe is a sequential series of instructions or other recipes.

Depending how one read that sentence, this can be ambiguous.

How about:

A recipe is a sequential series of instructions.

An instruction is either simple (a leaf) or complex (uses another recipe).

Which gives:

```
Table recipe:
- column id
- column name
- column total_cost, total_preparation_time, etc

Table instruction:
- column id
- column recipe_id
- column step_order
- column description
- column child_recipe_id (can be NULL)
```

So, if the peach tart uses dough and peach preserve:

```
select * from recipe order by id;
id      name
1       Dough
2       Peach preserve
3       Peach tart

select * from instruction order by recipe_id, step_order;
id recipe_id step_order description     child_recipe_id

100     1       1       Get flour       NULL
101     1       2       Add water       NULL
102     1       3       Mix together    NULL

201     2       1       Peel peaches    NULL
202     2       2       Cube peaches    NULL
203     2       3       Add sugar       NULL
204     2       4       Cook together   NULL

301     3       1       Pre heat oven   NULL
302     3       2       Prepare dough   1
303     3       3       Prepare peach   2
304     3       4       Bake            NULL
```

There are no "is leaf" flags.

An instruction is a leaf if it does not point to a child recipe, i.e. child_recipe_id is NULL.

Comment: In that sense, the `description`/`name` fields are redundant in respect to one another. How about having one table hold the tree of recipes, and the other just the names?

Comment: @Yuval, I don't see the recipe name and the instruction description that uses the recipe as redundant. The former describes "what" the resulting ingredient is (for example, "melted chocolate"), the later "how" the result is used (for example, "draw art in plate with melted chocolate"). Yumm.

Answer (score 0):

I may be way off here, but Recipe and instruction could be the same table, simplifying your relationships.

Instruction: id, name, is_recipe

Steps: parent_id, child_id, order

Now a recipe can have instructions and recipes as children. An instruction could even be to follow a recipe but with reduced butter...

You may need to add some loop-control though...